# Azure / Transact SQL: Dynamically create View of tables with the same name OR add tables after View creation

Tags: sql, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, sql-view

I'm new to Azure and not great with SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have a Database where each user has a Schema. Each Schema has identically structured tables with the same name, say "`Table`".

I now require a View in another Schema which provides a read-only union of all the rows from all the tables `Table`.

I was successful in creating a Schema, say `Views`, handling its permissions and creating a View, "`TableView`", with the following SQL from **Partitioned Views** @ [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-using-partitioned-datav):

```
CREATE VIEW Views.TableView
AS  
SELECT *
  FROM Schema1.Table
UNION ALL  
SELECT *
  FROM Schema2.Table
UNION ALL  
SELECT *
  FROM Schema3.Table
...
GO
```

I now wish for this View to be dynamic as future Schemas (`SchemaX`) are added or even possibly removed without having to repeatedly DROP and CREATE `TableView` over and over.

Is it possible to create the View in such a way that it would automatically query all tables with the same name? Or perhaps there is some way to 'add' an additional table post creation?

I can get a list of all `SchemaX.Table` by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but other than having a python script DROP and CREATE the View again I am lost.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like the real problem is you have a design flaw. Such a design doesn't scale and if you add a new user your `VIEW` isn't going to reflect this, and if you remove a user (and delete their schema and objects) then the `VIEW` will break. A Schema shouldn't store meta data such as who the data belongs to (the user) it should be a column in the table. What you *really* need to do here is fix the design.

Comment: Also note that to achieve this dynamically, it would be **impossible** to do in a `VIEW`. You would have to use a stored procedure, and that means you can't do simple things like `SELECT` from it, making it far harder to use.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry I did'nt describe it well. each Schema can be seen as the collection of data for a seporate buisness / department and has multiple users interacting with it. This was done to try and neaten up the DB as well as keep each buisness's data secure and in their control.

The reason for the View is to collect some data for read only use

Comment: That doesn't actually change any of my above statements, @stormpie . They all still applicable, even if you replace "user" with "business".

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. That's fair enough haha.
Can I ask you to elaborate on this though "A Schema shouldn't store meta data such as who the data belongs to (the user) it should be a column in the table." If you dont mind
How do you mean it should be a column? Do you mean ownership should be defined in a table or ...?
The reason for this was setting everyone's defualt schema to their buisness so they wouldnt have to worry about anything else in the DB. Ie. me, not being fluent in SQL trying to keep things overly simple I guess

Comment: So instead of having 17 tables, all identical, on different schemas you have one table, with a column `BusinessName`. Instead of `MySmartCompany.Mytable` you have a column in the table `dbo.MyTable` (or your generic schema), called `BusinessName` which has the value `'MySmartCompany'`.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I was fiddling on changing to one table with RLS at the same time but thought this would be easier :)

Thanks again

Comment: @stormpie do you need summarize the comments as the answer?

Comment: @LeonYue. Hi sorry I was away. Will do this evening unless you want to and I'll accept it?

Comment: Hi @stormpie, thanks Larnu and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @larnu's comments, it's very useful and professional:

- To achieve this dynamically, it would be **impossible** to do in a `VIEW`.
  You would have to use a stored procedure, and that means you can't do
  simple things like `SELECT` from it, making it far harder to use.
- Instead of having 17 tables, all identical, on different schemas you
  have one table, with a column `BusinessName`. Instead of
  `MySmartCompany.Mytable` you have a column in the table `dbo.MyTable` (or
  your generic schema), called `BusinessName` which has the value `'MySmartCompany'`.

This also can be beneficial to other community members.